# Aduino 7 segment dice project

Tags: programming, led, atmega328

I am struggling with the code that I should write for my project. I finished my breadboard but I have never learnt programming before so I cannot write the program for the dice.
My project is to make the dice output random numbers when the button is pressed.
This is what I have completed already. I just want to know how to complete the program to make it work for my arduino.
[image]

This is the code so far:

```
int leda = 2;
int ledb = 3;
int ledc = 4;
int ledd = 5;
int lede = 6;
int ledf = 7;
int ledg = 8;
int ledh = 9;
int leda1 = A0;
int ledb1 = A1;
int ledc1 = A2;
int ledd1 = A3;
int lede1 = A4;
int ledf1 = A5;
int ledg1 = A6;
int ledh1 = A7;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(leda, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(ledb, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(ledc, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(ledd, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(lede, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(ledf, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(ledg, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(ledh, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(leda1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(ledb1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(ledc1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(ledd1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(lede1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(ledf1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(ledg1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(ledh1, OUTPUT);

    pinMode(12, INPUT);

    digitalWrite(12, HIGH);
}

if (number == 1)
{
    digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(7, HIGH);
}

else if (number == 2)
{
    digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(5, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(8, HIGH);
    delay(200);
}
else if (number == 3)
{
    digitalWrite(3,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(2,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(5,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(7,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(8,HIGH);
    delay(200);
}

else if (number == 4)
{
    // do number 4
}

else if (number == 5)
{
    // do number 5
}

// ... etc
// Additional 'numbers' have been removed for brevity
```

Comment: Proper formatting, come on! It's a pain to add four spaces to the front of each line (I'm not being sarcastic, it really is!) but nobody likes reading it when it's like this. I'll edit it this time...

Comment: This looks horribly repetitive. See [Controlling 7 segment LED display from Arduino](https://www.electronicsblog.net/controling-7-segment-led-display-from-arduino-full-code-included/) for an example program that does work, and my comment to the same post for a more compact way of writing all this.

Comment: @chaaarlie2 It's not a pain - just highlight it and press the `{ }` button above the editor.

Comment: Don't forget you need to turn off the segments you no longer need on when you change from one number to another...

Comment: @Majenko: I didn't know that (or, rather, I think I forgot it); I'm horribly embarrassed.

Comment: @chaaarlie2 To be fair, the icon's not exactly very meaningful - easy to overlook it.

Comment: @Majenko ALL THOSE HOURS OF SPACEBAR-PRESSING I'LL NEVER GET BACK.

Answer (score 2):

### About random numbers

What you are trying to achieve is actually not that easy. An Arduino is
basically a computer, and as any computer, it is designed to execute
instructions in a very *deterministic* fashion. Computers are not good
at randomness and, unless fitted with dedicated hardware, they *cannot*
generate random numbers. Given this, you are left with two options:

1. [pseudo-random number generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator)
2. [entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_%28computing%29) gathering

The first is the easiest:

```c++
int first_dice  = random(1, 7);  // 1 (inclusive) to 7 (exclusive)
int second_dice = random(1, 7);
```

and voilà! You have two random-looking numbers. They are random-looking
in the sense that you will find no obvious pattern in any sequence of
numbers you draw. However, if you reset your Arduino, either with the
reset button or by power-cycling it, it will give you the *exact same
sequence* as in the first run. Thus, pseudo-randomness in useless unless
you commit to never unpower your circuit. It is a good starting point,
however, if your main goal is to get started with Arduino programming.

Entropy gathering means getting some randomness from outside the
Arduino: you would connect it to some source of randomness and perform
some measurement that has unpredictable outcome. A human being is a good
source of randomness: if you require the user to press a button before
displaying the dice value, the timing of the button press is a good
random source. The `micros()` function can be used to get the current
time with 4 µs resolution, which is more than enough for this
purpose. Entropy gathering is usually used in tandem with pseudo-random
number generators, as a way to *seed* them, like this:

```c++
wait_for_the_user_to_press_a_button();
randomSeed(micros());
int first_dice =  random(1, 7);
int second_dice = random(1, 7);
```

If you cannot have human interaction, you could try to get some
electromagnetic noise by performing an `analogRead()` on a floating pin.
Ideally you would connect that pin to an analog noise source. See the
first comment to this answer for more information on this option.

### About arrays and loops

You should definitely try to find a good tutorial about arrays and
loops. Whenever you find yourself writing tons of almost-identical lines
of code, you should wonder whether you can replace that repetition with
a loop. For example, for displaying the digit `1`, you may write:

```c++
if (number == 1) {
    digitalWrite(leda,  LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledb, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(ledc, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(ledd,  LOW);
    digitalWrite(lede,  LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledf,  LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledg,  LOW);
}
```

(I am using the "canonical" A–G letter assignments, and yes, you should
also take care of setting to `LOW` the segments you want to be off).
This code is an obvious candidate for being replaced by a loop:

```c++
if (number == 1) {
    for (int segment = 0; segment < 7; segment++)
        digitalWrite(leds[segment], digit1[segment]);
}
```

This requires that you first define the following arrays:

```c++
//                A     B     C     D     E     F     G
int leds[]   = {  2,    3,    4,    5,    6,    7,    8 };
int digit1[] = { LOW, HIGH, HIGH,  LOW,  LOW,  LOW,  LOW};
```

This logic can be pushed one level further by using a two-dimensional
array (an array of arrays): instead of defining six arrays `digit1`,
`digit2`... `digit6`, you create an array of arrays like this:

```c++
int digits[][7] = {
         /*          A     B     C     D     E     F     G  */
         /* 1 */  { LOW, HIGH, HIGH,  LOW,  LOW,  LOW,  LOW},
         /* 2 */  {HIGH, HIGH,  LOW, HIGH, HIGH,  LOW, HIGH},
         ...
};
```

and you use `digits[number]` instead of `digit1`, etc. This way you get
rid of the whole `if () ... else if ()` chain, replaced by:

```c++
for (int segment = 0; segment < 7; segment++)
    digitalWrite(leds[segment], digits[number-1][segment]);
```

Take care though that in C++ arrays are indexed from zero, which is why
you need to use `number-1` as the index in `digits`. If you have more
than one die (which is your case), you can also put their pin
assignments in a two-dimensional array. Then all the dice updating code
would be wrapped inside a loop indexed by the die number. Putting all
this together you end up with something like this:

```c++
// Pin assignments.
int leds[][7] = {
   /*                A     B     C     D     E     F     G  */
   /* 1st die */  {  2,    3,    4,    5,    6,    7,    8 },
   /* 2nd die */  { A0,   A1,   A2,   A3,   A4,   A5,   A6 }
};

// 7-segment "font".
int digits[][7] = {
         /*          A     B     C     D     E     F     G  */
         /* 1 */  { LOW, HIGH, HIGH,  LOW,  LOW,  LOW,  LOW},
         /* 2 */  {HIGH, HIGH,  LOW, HIGH, HIGH,  LOW, HIGH},
         /* 3 */  {HIGH, HIGH, HIGH, HIGH,  LOW,  LOW, HIGH},
         /* 4 */  { LOW, HIGH, HIGH,  LOW,  LOW, HIGH, HIGH},
         /* 5 */  {HIGH,  LOW, HIGH, HIGH,  LOW, HIGH, HIGH},
         /* 6 */  {HIGH,  LOW, HIGH, HIGH, HIGH, HIGH, HIGH}
};

void setup()
{
    for (int die = 0; die < 2; die++) {
        for (int segment = 0; segment < 7; segment++) {
            pinMode(leds[die][segment], OUTPUT);
        }
    }
}

void loop() {
    for (int die = 0; die < 2; die++) {
        int number = random(1, 7);
        for (int segment = 0; segment < 7; segment++)
            digitalWrite(leds[die][segment], digits[number][segment]);
    }
    delay(200);
}
```

This is still lacking the entropy gathering phase discussed above.

Comment: Connecting the analogue input to the collector of a run-of-the-mill transistor, with the emitter grounded and base open helps to make a noisy input. There's actually plenty of information about random noise generation techniques for this purpose on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

I made it so at least it compiles. It should loop through the numbers.

As for the circuit; you really should add a resistor to every segment, instead of just one the the common cathode. Otherwise the brightness will be different if more segments are on.

```
int number = 1;
int number1 = 1;

int leda = 2;
int ledb = 3;
int ledc = 4;
int ledd = 5;
int lede = 6;
int ledf = 7;
int ledg = 8;
int ledh = 9;

int leda1 = A0;
int ledb1 = A1;
int ledc1 = A2;
int ledd1 = A3;
int lede1 = A4;
int ledf1 = A5;
int ledg1 = A6;
int ledh1 = A7;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);

    pinMode(leda, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(ledb, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(ledc, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(ledd, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(lede, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(ledf, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(ledg, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(ledh, OUTPUT);

    pinMode(leda1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(ledb1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(ledc1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(ledd1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(lede1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(ledf1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(ledg1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(ledh1, OUTPUT);

    pinMode(12, INPUT);
    digitalWrite(12, HIGH);
}
void loop() {

    // turn off all leds
    digitalWrite(leda, LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledb, LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledc, LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledd, LOW);
    digitalWrite(lede, LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledf, LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledg, LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledh, LOW);

    digitalWrite(leda1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledb1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledc1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledd1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(lede1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledf1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledg1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledh1, LOW);


    if (number == 1)
    {
        digitalWrite(leda, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(ledf, HIGH);
        delay(200);
    }
    else if (number == 2)
    {
        digitalWrite(ledb, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(leda, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(ledd, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(ledh, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(ledg, HIGH);
        delay(200);
    }
    else if (number == 3)
    {
        digitalWrite(ledb,HIGH);
        digitalWrite(leda,HIGH);
        digitalWrite(ledd,HIGH);
        digitalWrite(ledf,HIGH);
        digitalWrite(ledg,HIGH);
        delay(200);
    }
    else if (number == 4)
    {
        digitalWrite(ledc,HIGH);
        digitalWrite(ledd,HIGH);
        digitalWrite(leda,HIGH);
        digitalWrite(ledf,HIGH);
        delay(200);
    }
    else if (number == 5)
    {
        digitalWrite(ledb,HIGH);
        digitalWrite(ledc,HIGH);
        digitalWrite(ledd,HIGH);
        digitalWrite(ledf,HIGH);
        digitalWrite(ledg,HIGH);
        delay(200);
    }
    else if (number == 6)
    {
        digitalWrite(ledb,HIGH);
        digitalWrite(ledc,HIGH);
        digitalWrite(ledd,HIGH);
        digitalWrite(ledf,HIGH);
        digitalWrite(ledg,HIGH);
        digitalWrite(ledh,HIGH);
        delay(200);
    }

    if (number1 == 1)
    {
        digitalWrite(A4, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(A1, HIGH);
        delay(200);
    }
    else if (number1 == 2)
    {
        digitalWrite(A5, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(A4, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(A7, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(A0, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(A2, HIGH);
        delay(200);
    }
    else if (number1 == 3)
    {
        digitalWrite(A5,HIGH);
        digitalWrite(A4,HIGH);
        digitalWrite(A7,HIGH);
        digitalWrite(A1,HIGH);
        digitalWrite(A2,HIGH);
        delay(200);
    }
    else if (number1 == 4)
    {
        digitalWrite(A6,HIGH);
        digitalWrite(A7,HIGH);
        digitalWrite(A4,HIGH);
        digitalWrite(A2,HIGH);
        delay(200);
    }
    else if (number1 == 5)
    {
        digitalWrite(A5,HIGH);
        digitalWrite(A6,HIGH);
        digitalWrite(A7,HIGH);
        digitalWrite(A1,HIGH);
        digitalWrite(A2,HIGH);
        delay(200);
    }
    else if (number1 == 6)
    {
        digitalWrite(A5,HIGH);
        digitalWrite(A6,HIGH);
        digitalWrite(A7,HIGH);
        digitalWrite(A0,HIGH);
        digitalWrite(A1,HIGH);
        digitalWrite(A2,HIGH);
        delay(200);
    }

    number = (number%6) + 1;//show next number the next loop
}
```